# How to perform version sort in Vim?

Tags: sort

I see that Vim has an `n` option for sorting based on the first decimal number on the line, but I'm looking for something like the `-V, --version-sort` option in the Linux sort command:

> ```
>  -V, --version-sort
>           natural sort of (version) numbers within text
> ```

Comment: I don't want to assume: are you aware that you can use external commands to manipulate vim's buffers?

Comment: @MDeBusk, thanks for the tip. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: I suspect you are referring to `read`, `write`, and filter. Now I need to learn how to combine them with text objects.

Comment: I'd visually select the lines I wanted to sort and type `:!sort -V`

Answer (score 2):

Echoing @MDeBusk's answer in the comments for better visibility:

> I'd visually select the lines I wanted to sort and type :!sort -V

Comment: In particular, `!` is also an operator, so, _e.g._, `!ipsort -V<enter>` does what you might hope